# How to evaluate quality of link prediction task?

Tags: python, algorithm, networking, prediction

I understand that here we can use precision, recall, AUC,  etc. I mean this: we have 4 users ('a', 'b', 'c', 'd') and we have got prediction that user 'a' will have link with 'b' with probability 0.7, with 'c' 0.4, and with 'd' 0.3, but really user 'a' added to friend list only  user 'c', so how to evaluate accuracy of our predictions?

Comment: Maybe you can set a threshold in your prediction algorithm, it can return multiple predictions if the probabilities of these predictions are above the threshold, which adds to flexibility.

Comment: Now the threshold does not matter. I don't understad the approach of evaluating. For example in recommendation systems we can get quality like this: the algorithm predicts y_pred = [0, 2, 1, 3] these rating, but true values are y_true = [0, 1, 2, 3], so using like accuracy_score(y_true, y_pred)  from sklearn we get 0.5. But how to evaluate the quality in my situation?

Comment: Well,i think there is no universal quality evaluation methods (except for Recall, Precision,etc.). So you can build your own rules and evaluation system in your specific situations. My experiences tell me different recommendation system varies a lot and their goals are also different, so you should adjust your evaluation according to your goal.

Answer (score 0):

Look into [Sklearn.Metrics](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/classes.html#module-sklearn.metrics) particularly `metrics.f1_score` and `metrics.confusion_matrix` as you clearly are doing a classification task.

Aditionally root-mean square error could help (average difference from the right value)
As you mentioned precision/recall-style tests, to see how many of the top N recommendations were "good" ones.
Finally you want to do some kind of A/B testing to see whether the recommendations are actually being useful recomendations based on a whatever business model metric you have(clicks/conversions)